# UIDatePicker issue with NSdate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

i have an NSDate object from an old date which i am getting from my DB. Now i need to set my UIDatePicker date to current date but with hour and minute value from my stored NSDate object which i have got from my DB.

So how to extract hour and minute from old date and set it to current UIDatePicker NSdate.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a NSDate can't be changed after it's initialization, you have to recreate it:

To get the hour and minute component of the NSDate use NSCalendar:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:yourOriginalDateHere];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];
```

Then you can create a new NSDate (also using NSCalendar):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit  | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; //[NSDate date] is the current date
[dateComponents setHour:hour];
[dateComponents setMinute:minute];
[dateComponents setSecond:second];
NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Comment: you are fast.. You posted the answer while I was typing.. +1 for that

Comment: thanks for the answer.Just one more doubt can this way i can set am/pm same way from my saved NSDATE and why we use NSGregorianCalendar. is it the default calender or i have to set any other calender in my case?

Comment: The Gregorian Calendar is the most common used calendar in the world, and the default calendar for iOS. As for AM/PM: NSDateComponents uses a 24-hour system (11:00 = 11:00 am, 13:00 = 1:00 PM , 16:00 = 4:00pm etc). If you convert to NSDate , the 24 hour value will properly change to AM/PM if the current datetime-locale of the app is a 12-hour system.

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *dbDateComps = [cal components:(kCFCalendarUnitHour | kCFCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:YOUR_DATE_FRM_DB];
 NSDateComponents *currentComps = [cal components:(kCFCalendarUnitYear | kCFCalendarUnitMonth | kCFCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
 [currentComps setHour:[dbDateComps hour]];
 [currentComps setMinute:[dbDateComps minute]];

 NSDate *resultDate = [currentComps date];
```